# php storm file not opening

Tags: phpstorm

I installed xampp, composer, nodejs and npm, created a project.
But when I used the command php storm, it shows as follows:

```
C:\Users\Hp>cd freeCodeGram

C:\Users\Hp\freeCodeGram>php storm .
Could not open input file: storm
```

Comment: Please check if you have added phpstorm to your windows path.

Comment: `php storm` calls the php file named `storm`. Pretty obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try without the space between php and storm

```
phpstorm .
```

you are now trying to run the file storm as a php command or whatever - that doesnt work :)

Comment: C:\Users\Hp\freeCodeGram>phpstorm  .
'phpstorm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You understand that all that command is trying to do is open phpstorm right?
Try opening phpstorm without using the command line